# Can not run React App after cloning it from Github

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, git-clone

I really need your help. I would be highly appreciated.

I clone this project : https://github.com/iearn-finance/iearn-finance,
and I want to have a front-end website like this: https://yearn.finance/.

But I can not run it **locally**. I have tried `"npm install"` and then `"npm start"`, check **package.json** carefully but it still does not work and gave me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path D:\iearn-finance-develop\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\iearn-finance-develop\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent
```

Comment: Did you `cd` *into* the directory after cloning it?

Comment: Yes, I did. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: It can’t find the package json file. Are you sure that you ran npm start from the directory which contains it?

Comment: Thanks for your all answers, I really appreciated it. It turns out i am not ran npm start in exactly directory file

Comment: I have fixed it

Comment: THANKS ALL FOLKS

Comment: So you didn't cd into the directory after cloning it.

Comment: Yes, It was mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- are you sure path **D:\iearn-finance-develop**  is correct??
isn't **D:\iearn-finance** ??

2-did you :
delete **package-lock.json** and **node_modules** and then **npm install**

3-check on your filesystem if the file exists.

try these :

**npm cache clean**

you should initialize package with :

**npm init**

then install your packages

Comment: I have already fixed it, It was my mistake when not put in the correct folder. Thanks with your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the cache with `npm cache clean`
Then initialize with `npm init`

After that, install your packages.
It worked for mine.